I can't connect my Android to any VPN except Kaspersky - How to fix?
I previously used 1.1.1.1 Warp VPN and it always used to work but it made my internet speed slow and so I'd keep it off. Later on, I tried Kaspersky VPN and it worked. I've tried many VPNs in the past too , they never showed any problems, but recently I can only connect to the VPN provided by Kaspersky and when I tried using 1.1.1.1 Warp it doesn't work (because I got premium there and want to use that instead).
And that's the same case for all other VPNs I've ever tried, I had them downloaded again and tried to connect, but they all say connection failed and doesn't work.
Kaspersky, on the other hand, does work even now, so I think that app changed some setting on my phone as it required but it's preventing other VPNs from working.
What should I do? I tried every solution video from YouTube, it still doesn't get fixed.

Have you tried uninstalling Kaspersky temporary?

Yes I have ,still the same

Please specify what exactly have you tried from solution Youtube videos. You might have conflicting VPN profiles, try deleting old VPN profiles you don't need. Also try clearing cache and saved data for your VPN Apps. Reinstall the apps, reset your network settings, check if you have the latestest software update installed.

Yeah, I've tried all of those you just told me about
